# Why my script does not work ? google maps, geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the array like this: "country, city, street", I want to get an array containing the coordinates of the points .
Reaching the line:

```
locations.push(results[0].geometry.location);
```

the script stops. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem ?

```
var addresses = ["Russia, Moscow, Arbet", "Estonia, Tallinn, Uus",...];
function initialize() 
{ 
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, addresses[i]);
    }
}
var locations = [];
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, address) 
{   
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        }
        else 
        {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' +     status);
        }
        locations.push(results[0].geometry.location);
    });
}
```

Thanks,
Irina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `google.maps.Geocoder.geocode` function returns status those value is different from `"OK"` then response does not contain the resolved location, so you might need to initialize `locations` array once the status is `google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK`:

```
if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
{
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
     });
     locations.push(results[0].geometry.location);
 }
```

**Modified example:**

```js
var addresses = ["Russia, Moscow, Arbet", "Estonia, Tallinn, Uus"];
var locations = [];

function initialize() 
{
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: {
            lat: 55.6574391,
            lng: 26.4077234
        },
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    addresses.forEach(function(address) {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, address,
            function (location) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: location
                });
                locations.push(location);
            },
            function (status) {
                console.log('Geocode error: ' + status);
            });
    });
       
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder,address, success, error) 
{   
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            success(results[0].geometry.location);
        }
        else 
        {
            error(status);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**Update: Example 2**

```js
var addresses = ["Russia, Moscow, Arbet", "Estonia, Tallinn, Uus"];
var locations = [];


function initialize() 
{
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: {
            lat: 57.6574391,
            lng: 19.4077234
        },
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


    var promises = getGeocodeAddressDeferred(geocoder, addresses);
    $.when.apply($, promises).done(function (location) {

        locations = arguments; // get all locations

        alert(JSON.stringify(locations)); //1.print all locations

        //display markers
        $.each(locations, function (i, location) {
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: location
              });
        });
    });       
}


function getGeocodeAddressDeferred(geocoder, addreses) {
    var promises = [];
    $.each(addreses, function (i, address) {
        promises.push(geocodeAddress(geocoder, address));
    });
    return promises;
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, address) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            deferred.resolve(results[0].geometry.location);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="map.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I need an array in which I can refer to each element

Comment: @quak, it's an expected behavior since `geocode` is _async_ operation. See the updated answer (**example 2**) that demonstrates how to resolve all the locations and then display markers

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, address) 
{   
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        }
        else 
        {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' +     status);
        }
        locations.push(results[0].geometry.location);
    });
}
```

`results` is passed as a parameter to your callback method, but you're trying to access it from outside the method, where it is not defined.